# What is the static variable initialization order across classes in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf

[DependencyProperty.AddOwner MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597484.aspx#exampleToggle) offers an example with two classes with static members, and the member of one class depends on the member of the other class for initialization. I think MSDN is wrong - the initialization order of static variables is unreliable in C# [just like it is in C++](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.12) or anywhere else. I'm probably wrong because the WPF library itself is written that way and it works just fine. What am I missing? How can C# compiler possibly know the safe initialization order?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's fine for one type to depend on another type being initialized, so long as you don't end up in a cycle.

Basically this is fine:

```
public class Child
{
    static Child() {} // Added static constructor for extra predictability
    public static readonly int X = 10;
}

public class Parent
{
    static Parent() {} // Added static constructor for extra predictability
    public static readonly int Y = Child.X;
}
```

The result is well-defined. `Child`'s static variable initializers are executed prior to the first access to any static field in the class, as per section 10.5.5.1 of the spec.

This isn't though:

```
public class Child
{
    public static readonly int Nasty = Parent.Y;
    public static readonly int X = 10;
}

public class Parent
{
    public static readonly int Y = Child.X;
}
```

In this latter case, you *either* end up with `Child.Nasty=0`, `Parent.Y=10`, `Child.X=10` *or* `Child.Nasty=0`, `Parent.Y=0`, `Child.X=10` depending on which class is accessed first.

Accessing `Parent.Y first` will start initializing `Parent` first, which triggers the initialization of `Child`. The initialization of `Child` will realise that `Parent` needs to be initialized, but the CLR knows that it's already being initialized, so carries on regardless, leading to the first set of numbers - because `Child.X` ends up being initialized before its value is used for `Parent.Y`.

Accessing `Child.Nasty` will start initializing `Child` first, which will then start to initialize `Parent`. The initialization of `Parent` will realise that `Child` needs to be initialized, but the CLR knows that it's already being initialized, so carries on regardless, leading to the second set of numbers.

**Don't do this.**

---

EDIT: Okay, more detailed explanation, as promised.

**When is a type initialized?**

If a type has a *static constructor*, it will only be initialized
when it's first used (either when a static member is referenced, or
when an instance is created). If it *doesn't* have a static
constructor, it can be initialized earlier. In theory, it could also
be initialized later; you could theoretically call a constructor or
a static method without the static variables being initialized - but
it *must* be initialized before static variables are referenced.

**What happens during initialization?**

First, all static variables receive their default values (0, null
etc).

Then the static variables of the type are initialized in textual
order. If the initializer expression for a static variable requires
another type to be initialized, then that other type will be
completely initialized before the variable's value is assigned -
*unless* that second type is already being initialized (due to a
cyclic dependency). Essentially, a type is either:

- Already initialized
- Being initialized at the moment
- Not initialized

Initialization is only triggered if the type is not initialized.
This means that when there are cyclic dependencies, it is possible
to observe a static variable's value *before its initial value has
been assigned*. That's what my `Child`/`Parent` example shows.

After all the static variable initializers have executed, the static
constructor executes.

See section 10.12 of the C# spec for more details on all of this.

---

By popular demand, here was my original answer when I thought the question was about the initialization order of static variables *within a class*:

Static variables are initialized in textual order, as per section 10.5.5.1 of the C# spec:

> The static field variable initializers
>   of a class correspond to a sequence of
>   assignments that are executed in the
>   textual order in which they appear in
>   the class declaration.

Note that partial types make this trickier as there's no one canonical "textual order" of the class.

Comment: Thank you for your brief appearance, Most Holy.

Comment: P.S. Your first post version had useful information. Bring it back please?

Comment: @New in town: it was useful but not relevant. Will add it as a subnote.

Comment: Jon, your both set of numbers are identical - 0, 10, 10. Could you correct please? I'm also not clear on the sequence of events - what do you mean by "carries on regardless"? Who exactly carries on? Could you please describe the process step by step?

Comment: So, in C#, all static variables have Initialize on First Use idiom implemented automatically and transparently by the CLR?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Now I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: @CannibalSmith: Well, the CLR will initialize the whole *type* when any of the static variables within it are referenced, yes. See the CLI spec for more details about the exact guarantees.

Comment: It seems that when using a partial class with multiple source files, the order of the static fields initialization will be based first on the order the sources are added to the Compile Include in the .csproj (and then by the textual order in each file). So if in a static field initialization in file B, you reference a static field from file A (both from the same partial class), make sure file A is compile included BEFORE file B in the csproj.

Comment: Just reading MSDN - seems to contradict @JonSkeet in that static members are initialized first, MSDN says "A static constructor is called automatically. It initializes the class before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced."  So the way I read this, is static constructers are called first before static members. I'm confused.

Comment: @Vidar: If a type has a static constructor, the static initializers for the variables are effectively hoisted there. I don't know offhand whether there's a guarantee about static initializers vs the code in the static constructor though. But what you quoted there is about what *triggers* class initialization - not the order in which the various initialization aspects happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about the order you could always place your code in the static constructor. This is where I register my dependency properties.

Answer (score 0):

No I think unreliable is not the correct word here.

In true single thread scenario, static members of class are initialized when any of static members of the type is first accessed in your code.

I am not aware of c++, but yes only in certain cases like in Multi threaded environment if two types trying to access shared resource and if that is static then its impossible to tell who will win and which one will work correct.

The MSDN Example is correct and that will work correctly.