# When do static declarations get run?

Tags: c#, static

Here's a piece of my code:

```
public class MyClass {
  public object Value { get; set; }

  public MyClass(object value) {
    this.Value = value;
  }
}

public class AnotherClass {
  private static MyClass _MyObj = new MyClass(new object());

  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    var x = _MyObj; // no problem
    var y = x.Value; // no problem
    var z = y.ToString(); // Null ref exception
  }
}
```

I don't understand how this can be. `_MyObj` is not null, which means that the inline assignment did work, yet `_MyObj.Value` comes out null, meaning that the constructor code wasn't invoked!  There's some dark magic at work here, and I'd greatly appreciate an explanation.

Thanks!

**EDIT** - sorry about the no repro.  My actual code is (obviously) more complex than this, so I tried to dumb it down, and obviously in the process I must have removed some other obstruction to the code's proper function.  But [Kobi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944704/when-do-static-declarations-get-run/1944720#1944720) is really what I was trying to get out of this question, anyway - so answer credit to him.  :)

Comment: This code won't even compile, as you don't have a setter for the Value property.

Comment: Which compiler? Works fine under VS2008/.NET3.5 as soon as I add a setter for the Value property.

Comment: Either way, there's little to be added to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405709/what-is-the-static-variable-initialization-order-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way to initialize static members is by using a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc%28VS.80%29.aspx):

```
static AnotherClass(){
  _MyObj = new MyClass(new object());
}
```

Comment: That's a style issue, your code is exactly the same as `private static MyClass _MyObj = new MyClass(new object());`

Comment: @Henk - I realize that, but it can still help in a more complex scenario, as Shaul said.

Answer (score 2):

Status: No repro.

The code sample as provided does not compile, `public object Value { get; }` is not a valid auto-property.

After fixing it with a `private set;` it compiles and runs w/o error.

Answer (score 1):

Put a setter and it will work as expected:

```
public object Value { get; set; }
```