# Initialization of static members

Tags: c#

```
class Test
{
   private static int m = 10;
   private static double n = 20;

   public Test()
   {

   }
}
```

If a static constructor is used, the static variables are initialized when the first instance of the class is constructed or the first variable is referred. If I don't use a static constructor, when are the static variables initialized and in what order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405709/what-is-the-static-variable-initialization-order-in-c/1405729#1405729

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C# Language Specification, [section 10.4.5.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758.aspx), says:

> If a static constructor exists in the class, execution of the static field initializers
>   occurs immediately prior to executing
>   that static constructor. Otherwise,
>   the static field initializers are
>   executed at an
>   implementation-dependent time prior to
>   the first use of a static field of
>   that class.

So, it's implementation-dependent, but all the static fields are guaranteed to be initialized before one of them is used.

Comment: Just look at the generated class with Reflector, you will see the static constructor there.

Comment: @Aliostad, *some* compilers might do that, but not all, that's why it's implementation-dependent :)

Comment: The static field variable initializers of a class correspond to a sequence of assignments that are executed in the textual order in which they appear in the class declaration.  what does the textual order means?

Comment: "*some* compilers might do that". Well, I thought we are talking about C# compiler?? :) I said compiler spits out...

Comment: @Raghav55, it means the order in which the parser encounters them, i.e. the order they're declared in the class.

Comment: @Aliostad, sorry, I should have said *some C# compilers*.

Comment: @Frederic Hamidi: if i have static intitalizers do i need to have static constructor. or in general which is the best way to intitalize the static variables through static intitalizers or through constructors

Comment: @Raghav55, it's a matter of personal preference (or company coding rules, which usually take precedence). I personally prefer field initializers, but constructors are fine too :)

Answer (score 1):

In C#4.0, static fields are initialized as lazy as possible without a static constructor.. While in previous versions, we can't give an exact initialization time. Jon Skeet has [a great post](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/01/26/type-initialization-changes-in-net-4-0.aspx) about this.

Answer (score -1):

Same place. *Compiler* spits out the static constructor for you. Order is the one members are defined.

---

If you look at the class with **Reflector**, you can see the static constructor:

```
public class MyStaticClass
{
    public static int MyInt = 10;
}
```

Becomes:

```
public class MyStaticClass
{
    // Fields
    public static int MyInt;

    // Methods
    static MyStaticClass();
    public MyStaticClass();
}
```

With

```
static MyStaticClass()
{
    MyInt = 10;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly. If there is no explicit static constructor, the behavior is not the same.

Comment: is there any difference between these two private static int m=10 or Test() { m =10}