# C# - when at runtime is a const field initialized

Tags: c#, class, static, field, constants

For some reason, I've failed to find documentation on this.
It looks like, in C#, the const fields of a class are initialized before static fields, as it can be seen from this code:

```
class Program {
    static int p = f;
    const int f = 10;

    static void Main(string[] args){
        System.Console.WriteLine("{0}", p);
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

(this outputs `10`, while if I replace `const` with `static`, it outputs `0`).

The question is:
Is such behaviour always the case?
Also, what is, generally, the order of initialization of different kinds of static class fields?

Comment: *const*s are compile time values. static variables are initialized at runtime in the order they declared...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Constants are not initialised at all, they are constant values that are substituted at compile time. When the code runs, it's as if it was originally:

```
static int p = 10;
```

A side effect of this compile time substitution, is that constants that exist in one assembly and used in a different assembly requires both assemblies to be recompiled if you change the constant.

Comment: Thank you, I had some trouble comprehending it in the context of fields.

Answer (score 4):

`const` declares a value that is determined at *compile* time. In the compiled code, it appears simply as a literal, rather than a reference to some named identifier. So, yes…`const` members are always "initialized" before any other member, inasmuch as they are "initialized" at all.

Here is a reasonably complete answer to your broader question: [What is the static variable initialization order in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405709/what-is-the-static-variable-initialization-order-in-c)

Here are a couple of links to the documentation that should help as well:

[10.4.5.1 Static field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758(v=vs.71).aspx)

[10.4.5.2 Instance field initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645759(v=vs.71).aspx)