# "An item of the same key has already been added" despite the keys being guaranteed different

Tags: c#, .net, .net-8.0, c#-12.0

The code below seemingly results in a `System.TypeInitializationException` whenever anything in the Define class is called. The pairs are guaranteed to be different as shown below, and no code modifies the dictionary in any way. Yet the error `ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Key1` is thrown without fail every time. Is there any reason this happens?

```
public static class Define
{
    public static readonly Dictionary<DefineChoices, string> Definitions = new([Pair1, Pair2]);

    public enum DefineChoices
    {
        Key1,
        Key2
    }

    public static readonly KeyValuePair<DefineChoices, string> Pair1 = new(DefineChoices.Key1, "string1");
    public static readonly KeyValuePair<DefineChoices, string> Pair2 = new(DefineChoices.Key2, "string2");
```

Stack trace below:

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Program.Namespace.Define' threw an exception.
 ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Key1
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Program.Namespace.Define..cctor() in FilePath\Define.cs:line 2
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Static member initialization order within a single C# class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55368192/11683)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialization order is significant while initializing static fields. So if you arrange your class like the below it will work :

```
public static class Define
    {
        public static readonly KeyValuePair<DefineChoices, string> Pair1 = new(DefineChoices.Key1, "string1");
        public static readonly KeyValuePair<DefineChoices, string> Pair2 = new(DefineChoices.Key2, "string2");
        public static readonly Dictionary<DefineChoices, string> Definitions = new([Pair1, Pair2]);
        
        public enum DefineChoices
        {
            Key1,
            Key2
        }       
    }
```

The question of why you are getting a duplicate key of `Key1` is because it has the default uninitialized value of integer which is 0. Even if your enum would start with `1` as the start value you would get a duplicate key value of `0`.

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WfuHNc)

Comment: I wish the compiler would at least issue a warning that when initializing another field, 'Pair1' and 'Pair2' still have their default values ​​and their initializer hasn't run yet. If you initialize a list like this you won't even get an exception.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes %100 true, I think it should not be that hard to provide an analyzer to detect these kinds of scenarios and throw out a warning. I will check the repo if such an analyzer is requested if not I will create one.

Comment: I was about to do the same. I think it should be a compiler warning. Warnings are already issued for similar cases: *CS0649  Warning  Field '{0}' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value {1}*

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes the related [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/72164).

Comment: I found the [Proposal Warn before using static field initialiser that contains other static field from same class #12245](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12245) concerning this exact case. It is still open. CyrusNajmabadi says: "You can write an analyzer that looks for this sort of thing. You could also suggest this as something that dotnet/roslyn-analyzers might want to add."

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes just noticed right after I opened my issue, the sad part is it has been almost 4 years since the last comment, maybe they reconsider it when referencing my duplicate issue.

Comment: In your issue you say "... and are initialized before being referenced.". Shouldn't it be: "... and are referenced before the explicit initializer runs."? (The the implicit initialization with the default value still runs.)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes nice catch, I asked to chatgpt clean up my issue, and that's what I got :(

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to the order of intialization.
Simply put the Pairs ontop.
Reason is that those `KeyValueParir`s are structs so their unitialized values is basically `Key1` which then is added twice.

```
public static readonly KeyValuePair<DefineChoices, string> Pair1 = new(DefineChoices.Key1, "string1");
public static readonly KeyValuePair<DefineChoices, string> Pair2 = new(DefineChoices.Key2, "string2");
public static readonly Dictionary<DefineChoices, string> Definitions = new([Pair1, Pair2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why I switch to [static constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors) (if don't forget/overlook) when I have complex/interdepended initialization logic for static fields/properties:

```
public static class Define
{
    static Define()
    {
        Pair1 = new(DefineChoices.Key1, "string1");
        Pair2 = new(DefineChoices.Key2, "string2");
        Definitions = new([Pair1, Pair2]);
    }

    public static readonly Dictionary<DefineChoices, string> Definitions;

    public static readonly KeyValuePair<DefineChoices, string> Pair1;
    public static readonly KeyValuePair<DefineChoices, string> Pair2;
    // ...
}
```

So you can explicitly control the order of initialization and don't need to rely on correctly ordering members of the type (as explained earlier by [@Eldar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12354911/eldar) you have bumped into an issue caused by the fact that `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is a value type and has a default value with key equal to `default(TKey)` and the order of static members initialization determined by their order of declaration in the containing type).