# Instantiating Configuration in static mode

Tags: c#

I am trying to set global variables. After some reading, it seems that I can do that building a global class but it needs to be static. I've done it like that:

```
public static class Globals
{
    static Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.BasePath = "https://api.gateio.ws/api/v4";
    config.SetGateApiV4KeyPair("abc", "abc");

    static AccountApi apiInstance = new AccountApi(config);
 
    public static List<String> listing = [];
}
```

But of course, as it is static, I cannot set BasePath, nor SetGateApiV4KeyPair after instantiating the config object. So how could i do that please?

Comment: Have you tried to declare Config as a public static property in Globlas class scope?

Comment: [Static Constructors (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors)

Comment: I'm pretty new in C#, so I've no idea what it means...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always move the creation logic to a static method and call it:

```
public static class Globals
{
    private static Configuration config = CreateConfig();

    private static Configuration CreateConfig()
    {
        var result = new Configuration();
        config.BasePath = "https://api.gateio.ws/api/v4";
        config.SetGateApiV4KeyPair("abc", "abc");
        return result;
    }
    
    // ...
}
```

Another approach can be the usage the static constructor as in the answer provided [@Olivier Jacot-Descombes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880990/olivier-jacot-descombes). But it worth noting that the order of initialization can be very important (see for example this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78012300/an-item-of-the-same-key-has-already-been-added-despite-the-keys-being-guarante)). I highly recommend to move all the initialization for "complex"/interdepended cases into static ctor so the correct order is explicit and you should not worry about other implementation details (like what `AccountApi` actually does with `Configuration` or how the order of initialization is working):

```cs
public static class Globals
{
    private static readonly Configuration config;

    private static readonly AccountApi apiInstance;

    // Static constructor
    static Globals()
    {
        config = new()
        {
            BasePath = "https://api.gateio.ws/api/v4"
        };
        config.SetGateApiV4KeyPair("abc", "abc");
        apiInstance = new(config);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a [Static Constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors).

```cs
public static class Globals
{
    static readonly Configuration config = new() { // Target typed new
        BasePath = "https://api.gateio.ws/api/v4" // Object initializer
    };

    static readonly AccountApi apiInstance = new(config);  // Target typed new

    public static readonly List<String> listing = [];

    // Static constructor
    static Globals()
    {
        config.SetGateApiV4KeyPair("abc", "abc");
    }
}
```

Unlike instance constructors, it cannot have parameters.

It is also a good idea to make all fields that will keep the same value `readonly`. Note that for reference types this means that the `Globals` class will hold the same object reference throughout its life-time, but the content of these objects can still be changed. E.g., you can still add items to the list.

I also used an [Object initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers) and a [Target-typed new expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator#target-typed-new).

---

As you can see in this [SharpLab demo](https://sharplab.io/#gist:388fab573e4f11ab61dcf329c485bb8d), the code above is equivalent to:

```cs
public static class Globals
{
    private static readonly Configuration config;

    private static readonly AccountApi apiInstance;

    public static readonly List<string> listing;

    static Globals()
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.BasePath = "https://api.gateio.ws/api/v4";
        config = configuration;
        apiInstance = new AccountApi(config);
        listing = new List<string>();
        config.SetGateApiV4KeyPair("abc", "abc");
    }
}
```

A lot of C# features are said to be [Syntactic sugar](https://Syntactic%20sugar). I.e., they are provided for convenience but are implemented by other more basic features.

Comment: And how do I link that static Globals() with my static Configuration config = new Configuration(); ?

Comment: Personally I would move `apiInstance = new(config);` into the static ctor too.

Comment: @GuruStron, technically it makes no difference. All field initializers will be implemented in the constructor. See [Sharplab.io demo](https://sharplab.io/#gist:388fab573e4f11ab61dcf329c485bb8d)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yes, I have some idea how static members (including ctors) work =) It actually can make a huge difference even in this case and the decompilation clearly shows that. Obviously it hugely depends on what `AccountApi` ctor actually does, for example if it actually copies data from the  `Configuration` and does not store instance to use later - then it will copy data BEFORE the `SetGateApiV4KeyPair` call which can lead to incorrect data being fetched from the config.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes not to mention that you will make code less brittle due to it not relying on fields initialization order (for example imagine someone "refactoring" the order of `config` and `apiInstance`)

Comment: @GuruStron, yes, field initialization order is a problem and the compiler does not issue a warning if you get it wrong. Recently I stumbled over such a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78012300/880990). [Eldar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12354911/eldar) filed an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/72164) to the roslyn (C# compiler) github repo.